# Is this a counter example? (a linear bounded operator that is not continuous).

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

We know that $\mathbb{R}$² equipped with the standard euclidean norm is a normed vector space, let F be the map from $(\mathbb{R}²,\|.\|)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined for every $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}$²:

F(x,y)=

{$x+y$  for (x,y) in  $\mathbb{R}$$\times$0/[2,3]$\times$[2,3]}

{$2(x+y)$ for (x,y) in [2,3]$\times$[2,3]}

{0 elsewhere}

Is this map linear?

Is it bounded?

Is it continues for every point in $\mathbb{R}$²

Comment: $R'$ isn't a normed vector space.

Comment: It is not even a vector space. *Hint*: What is $1.2 + 1.3$?

Comment: What if we included the interval [2,3] but supposed that the operator F is just not defined on it?

Comment: I have Edited the question.

Comment: $F$ IS continuous from $\mathbb R$ \ $[2,3]$ to $\mathbb R.$  The restriction of any continuous $f:A\to B$ to a subspace $A'$  of $A$ is continuous from $A'$  to $B.$

Comment: Okay; I have edited it again what about this attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the maps proposed in the multiple versions of the question (so far) is linear. A linear map has to be defined on a vector space$~S$ (possible a vector subspace of another vector space), and if $S$ is finite dimensional with basis $b_n,\ldots,b_n$ then *any* linear map $f:S\to W$ satisfies $$f(x_1b_1+\cdots+x_nb_n)=x_1w_1+\cdots+x_nw_n$$
for certain vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_n$. This is simply the requirement of linearity of$~f$, taking $w_i=f(b_i)$. None of your examples respect this general form, so they are not linear maps.